# Стилизация input type="date"

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Как сделать иконку календаря вместо стрелок в поле ввода даты, как [здесь](http://voky.com.ua/showcase/sky-forms-pro/examples/demo-order.html)?

[image: пример выбора даты]

Comment: Там не input type=date.

Comment: я имею ввиду, у меня input type=date и как мне вместо стрелки запилить такую иконку?

Answer (score 3):

Для Хрома:

```css
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=16&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<input type=date>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!

```
<input type="date" />
```

Не всегда работает корректно - допустим в IE.
Попробуйте использовать [DatePicker jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). В том числе есть расширенная вариация [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) - Позволяет выбирать диапазоны дат, и достаточно гибко настраивается.